# How to convert a string to a list? 12345

Tags: python, string, list

I saved a `list` to a `csv` and want to import it again but it's in `string` format now. Is there a simple way to convert it to a `list` again?

```
string = '[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]'

L = list(map(int, string))

print(L)
```

Error:

```
L = list(map(int, string))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string representation of list to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
string = eval(string)
```

This will evaluate the expression as list of tuples, and from there adjust to your needs.

The reason for the error you get is because `map` pass each character from `string` to int, and `string[0]` is not a valid character that can be converted to an integer value.